# 'nonstandard' output on the Bitcoin blockchain

Tags: bitcoin

Can someone explain how a nonstandard output is spendable in another transaction? *(Since it doesn't have an address for the bitcoins to come from)*

```
# bitcoin-cli getblock "00000000000005f1eb5bb5f6b50e6a9f47182335aa0c749b0e8a43b53daad5c4" 2
{
  ...
  "tx": [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    {
      "txid": "8ebe1df6ebf008f7ec42ccd022478c9afaec3ca0444322243b745aa2e317c272",
      ...
      "vin": [
        ...
        {
          "txid": "db3f14e43fecc80eb3e0827cecce85b3499654694d12272bf91b1b2b8c33b5cb",
          "vout": 2,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "3045022100f4ece69a7c50c911b3af6fa017dcf22de4df66699cd85c5753634d85140b955602204996b677af3a0b5835b36ae1db6323a125f1525edd4727be3209a0535073f422[ALL] 0412b80271b9e034006fd944ae4cdbdbc45ee30595c1f8961439385575f1973019b3ff615afed85a75737ff0d43cd81df74bc76004b45a6e7c9e2d115f364da1d7",
            "hex": "483045022100f4ece69a7c50c911b3af6fa017dcf22de4df66699cd85c5753634d85140b955602204996b677af3a0b5835b36ae1db6323a125f1525edd4727be3209a0535073f42201410412b80271b9e034006fd944ae4cdbdbc45ee30595c1f8961439385575f1973019b3ff615afed85a75737ff0d43cd81df74bc76004b45a6e7c9e2d115f364da1d7"
          },
          "sequence": 4294967295
        },
        ...
      ]
    { ... },
    }
  ]
  ...
}
...
# bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction "db3f14e43fecc80eb3e0827cecce85b3499654694d12272bf91b1b2b8c33b5cb" 2
{
  "txid": "db3f14e43fecc80eb3e0827cecce85b3499654694d12272bf91b1b2b8c33b5cb",
  ...
  "vin": [
    ...
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      "value": 0.00065536,
      "n": 2,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 6300bf4c5c2a724c280b893807afb976ec78a92b OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG OP_NOP",
        "hex": "76a9146300bf4c5c2a724c280b893807afb976ec78a92b88ac61",
        "type": "nonstandard"
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addresses are just a convenient representation of common scripts, namely p2pkh, p2sh, p2wpkh, and p2wsh scripts.

The script in your example is simply a p2pkh script with an additional OP_NOP. As an OP_NOP is a... nop, it does not change the script in this case at all.

You can spend it the same way as a regular p2pkh output.